# node.js sqlite database connection (frontend angular.js)

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, nodes

I need to create to-do list, and first version worked well (without database connection).

index.html

```
<div id="todoCard" ng-repeat="task in taskList">
                <div id="label">
                    <label id="description" class="description" ng-class="{strike: task.done}">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="task.done"/>
                        {{task.description}}

                        <table id="buttons">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <button id="edit" ng-click="editTodo()">Edit</button>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <button id="del" ng-click="deleteTodo($index)">Del</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

controller.js

```
'use strict';
angular.module('toDoApp.controller',[])
.controller('toDoController',["$scope", function($scope){


    $scope.newTask = "";
    $scope.taskList = [
        {description: "Buy airplane tickets", done:false},
        {description: "Make hotel reservation", done:false},
        {description: "Lorem Ipsum", done:true}
    ];

    $scope.addTodo = function() {
        $scope.taskList.push({description: $scope.newTask, done:false});
        $scope.newTask = "";
    }

    $scope.deleteTodo = function(index) {
        $scope.taskList.splice(index, 1);

    }

}]);
```

But after that I connected to sqlite database and wanted to show cards from database.

Here is the connection:

factory.js

```
'use strict';
angular
    .module('toDoApp')
    .factory('toDoAppFactory', function(){
        var sqlite3     = require('sqlite3').verbose();
        var fs          = require('fs');

        // Setup database:
        var dbFile = 'database.db';
        var dbExists = fs.existsSync(dbFile);

        // If the database doesn't exist, create a new file:
        if(!dbExists)
        {
            fs.openSync(dbFile, 'w');
        }

        // Initialize the database:
        var db = new sqlite3.Database(dbFile);

        // Optional installation for newly created databases:
        if(!dbExists)
        {
            db.run('CREATE TABLE `todocards` (' +
            '`id` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,' +
            '`created` TEXT NOT NULL,' +
            '`deadline` TEXT NOT NULL,' +
            '`done` INTEGER NOT NULL,' +
            '`description` TEXT NOT NULL)');
        }

        // Insert some data using a statement:
        var statement = db.prepare('INSERT INTO `todocards` (`created`, `deadline`, `done`, `description`) ' +
        'VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');
        statement.run('2016-05-09', '2016-05-12', Math.round(Math.random() * 1), 'Ipsum');
        statement.finalize();

        db.each("SELECT * FROM `todocards`", function (err, row) {
            var taskList = JSON.stringify(row);

          });

        function getCards(taskList) {
                return taskList;
            }
            return {
            getCards: getCards
            }
db.close();


    });
```

controllers.js has been modified to:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('toDoApp.controller',[])
.controller('toDoController',["$scope", function($scope, toDoAppFactory){


    $scope.newTask = {};
    $scope.taskList = toDoAppFactory.getCards();





}]);
```

factory.js has been included to index.html
I've tested factory.js with console.log, `var taskList = JSON.stringify(row);` has an array. But something wrong.

Please, help with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you have the table and data ready.. so

in factory.js

```
var taskList = [];// create and array outside to store your rows
//.each iterates over each row. so push them in array array
db.each("SELECT * FROM `todocards`", function (err, row) {
     taskList.push(JSON.stringify(row));
});

function getCards() { //dont pass in any parameters here
    console.log(taskList); //just a small check..
    return taskList;
}
```

Comment: Debugging this variant:

Comment: Debugging this variant: rows are pushed in table, but console.log(taskList) shows nothing...